# Got same first name and last name on my domestic flight ticket

Tags: air-travel, india, domestic-travel

I was booking a round trip flight ticket from Delhi to  Leh, India. I got the same first name and last name in my ticket as "G VIMAL G VIMAL". My id consists of just G VIMAL. Is that be a problem?

Comment: not easy to confirm anything. I recommend you to ask your travel agent!

Comment: better you ask your travel agent for change or website if you have book online.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anyone can give you a definitive answer here. **The only valid answer is: it depends**.

This makes me wonder, is this actually a mistake? Names that don't fit the standard FIRSTNAME LASTNAME often get doubled or otherwise changed. My boarding pass for example would always show Johnfrank Doe while my passport says John Frank Chris Doe.

Your options:

First of all, try to correct the mistake (assuming it was a mistake). If you booked through an agency, contact them. It is most likely their responsibility to get it resolved. If that is not the case, contact the airline. See if they can change this for you.

Should this not be possible or really expensive then not all is lost! Do you have the option to check in online? If you do, use it and provide the correct details now. Can you only check in physically? Go to the airport as early as possible to get it sorted. Are you checked in with the incorrect name already and you can't change it? Also go to the airport early.

In my experience a boarding pass with an obvious error like this will often be accepted. But, as I said at the start of this post, it entirely depends. It depends on the airline, on the mood of the person checkin you in, etc.

The only extra advice I can give you: be friendly and reasonable about it, even if it's not your fault.